# Scheme - iterate and replace elements of list

Tags: list, loops, scheme

In scheme, if i have a list

```
('foo 'foo 8 'foo 9)
```

and another list

```
(1 2 4)
```

I want my resulting list to be

```
(1 2 8 4 9)
```

I know the basic logic: iterate through list 1. If 'foo, replace with car of list 2.

I'm having trouble writing this, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number of elements in the replacements list is the same as the number of `foo`s in the input list, we just have to traverse both lists and make a replacement whenever `foo` is found, we can "loop" across the lists using recursion:

```
(define (replace lst rep)
  (cond ((or (null? lst) (null? rep))
         lst)
        ((eq? (car lst) 'foo)
         (cons (car rep) (replace (cdr lst) (cdr rep))))
        (else
         (cons (car lst) (replace (cdr lst) rep)))))
```

For example:

```
(replace '(foo foo 8 foo 9) '(1 2 4))
=> '(1 2 8 4 9)
```